# Custom order type then shipping hiding in WooCommerce but still appear again

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function that is supposed to hide the shipping type when a specific order type has been selected. It works for about a second, but after the checkout page is completed, the other shipping options keep reappearing.

I am using Free Shipping (ID: 7), Flat Rate (ID: 6), and the Astra theme.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thank you!

```
// Add the custom field for "Order Type"
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_billing', 'before_billing_fields', 5);

function before_billing_fields() {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;

    echo '<h3>' . __('Order Type', 'sdm') . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field('delivery_method', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'delivery' => __('Delivery', 'sdm'),
            'dine_in' => __('Dine In', 'sdm'),
            'pick_up' => __('Pick Up', 'sdm'),
        ),
        'class' => array('delivery_method form-row-wide'),
        'clear' => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value('delivery_method'));


}

// The jQuery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_script' );
function custom_checkout_script() {
    // Only on the checkout page
    if( ! is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( function($){
            var a = 'select#delivery_method',
                b = 'input[name^="shipping_method[0]"]',
                d = 'flat_rate:6', // Flat Rate ID (replace with your actual Flat Rate ID)
                e = 'free_shipping:7'; // Free Shipping ID (replace with your actual Free Shipping ID)

            // Function to set shipping method to Free Shipping
            function setFreeShipping() {
                $(b + '[value="' + e + '"]').prop("checked", true);
                $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
            }

            // Function to set shipping method to Flat Rate
            function setFlatRate() {
                $(b + '[value="' + d + '"]').prop("checked", true);
                $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
            }

            // Function to hide unselected shipping methods
            function hideUnselectedShipping() {
                var selectedMethod = $(b + ':checked').val();
                $(b).each(function() {
                    var id = $(this).val();
                    if (id != selectedMethod) {
                        $(this).closest('li').hide();
                    } else {
                        $(this).closest('li').show();
                    }
                });
            }

            // Set the default delivery method to "Delivery" and trigger change event
            $(a).val('delivery').change();
            hideUnselectedShipping();

            // Live action event: On Select "delivery_method" change
            $(a).change( function () {
                if ($(this).val() == 'pick_up' || $(this).val() == 'dine_in') {
                    setFreeShipping(); // Change to Free Shipping for Dine In or Pick Up
                } else {
                    setFlatRate(); // Change to Flat Rate for Delivery
                }
                hideUnselectedShipping();
            });

            // Live action event: On Shipping method change
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', b, function() {
                // If Free shipping is not selected, we change "delivery_method" select field to "post"
                if ($(this).val() != e) {
                    $(a).val('delivery');
                    setFlatRate(); // Change to Flat Rate when another method is selected
                }
                hideUnselectedShipping();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: WooCommerce uses AJAX. Perhaps it's overwriting your changes.  Try tapping into that event.

Comment: You should try to better explain what you are trying to do, with the necessary context and details… As you are triggering "checkout_update" event in your code, it's normal that the hidden fields that you have hidden previously become visible back.

Comment: I would like to hide is permanent until user click confirmation. I don't want buyer see other rate because for delivery need to be pay some amount but for dine in and pick up is free. If buyer need delivery, and same time can see free shipping they will click change to free shipping.